# Assign Value of Loop Counter to Cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to run a scenario analysis in Excel:

I have scenarios 1 to XX in the workbook, which then assigns values to fields based on the scenario selected.

I'm trying to assign the variable i to the cell "ScenarioSwitch" via loop.

```
Sub Sensitivity()

Dim i As Integer
Dim MaxScenario As Long

MaxScenario = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Income").Range("E76", Range("E76").End(xlDown)).Count

For i = 1 To MaxScenario

    Range("ScenarioSwitch").Value = i

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `MaxScenario = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Income").Range("E76", Range("E76").End(xlDown)).Count`... first, you need to qualify the workbook/worksheet for `Range("E76")`. Then... your loop is basically the same as `Range("ScenarioSwitch").Value = MaxScenario`.... unless you've left out other code inside the loop.

Comment: It looks like the code is doing what you describe: ScenarioSwitch is being set 1 to MaxScenario. Shouldn't you be running the scenario after each change? The current code just races to the last scenario so you won't see any results for the previous scenarios.

Comment: @Mike67 you are correct, currently the code will be just running through - there will be more to the code going forward, here is what I have in mind: 1. Update Scenario 1 to MaxScenario - this will change inputs in model through lookup 2. Call Seperate Macro (this one takes care of circulate ref issue) 3. Copy Results to output table, next loop does the same with Scenario +1 and copy output under previous

Comment: @GMalc not sure if I fully understand the question, the scenario is in cell 76 - and starts at 1 and then goes to MaxScenario based on the number of scenarios I have in the table. The 1 to MaxScenario is basically a switchbox to update inputs that run to the model. I can't use datatable because the model has a circulate reference that is dealt with by seperate macro that will be called in the code. Haven't modeled it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Long` not `Integer` for declaring for loop variables.
If you need to loop through Column E starting at row 76 then you can just begin your for loop at 76.

```
Sub Sensitivity()

Dim i As Long
Dim MaxScenario As Long

MaxScenario = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Income").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 76 To MaxScenario

Range("A" & i).Value = i

Next i

End Sub
```